# Difference between the "Hazard Rate" and the "Killing Function" of a diffusion model?

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, wiener-measure

I posted this question on Cross Validated - but I think it applies here too. Also, it increases the chances of the question being answered.

Link [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169310/what-is-the-difference-between-the-hazard-rate-and-the-killing-function-of-a)

If this is not acceptable - administrators please delete, and anybody else please do not take points away from me for this reason.

```
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

***What is the difference between the "Hazard Rate" and the "Killing Function" of a diffusion model?***

Some Definitions:

The Killing Function

The function *k(t,x)* is interpreted as the killing rate. Informally, this means that if, at time *t*, the particle is alive and is situated at the point *x*, then the probability that it dies in the next *h* units of time is approximately *k(t,x)h* when *h* is small.

\begin{gather*}
Pr(\rho  \leq t+h \mid \rho  > t, X(t) = x)\approx k(t, x)h & (1)
\end{gather*}

And,

\begin{gather*}
dX(t) = \mu dt+\sigma dW\ & (2)
\end{gather*}

Hazard Rate

\begin{gather*}
Pr(t \leq T \leq t+h \mid T > t) \approx \lambda (t)h & (3)
\end{gather*}

That is, *λ(t)h* represents the instantaneous chance that an individual will die in the interval *(t, t + h)* given that this individual is alive at age *t*.

Lastly, to put it in perspective here is a picture of a diffusion with arbitrary Killing Function *k(x) = a + Sqrt(t/b)*, where a, and b are some constants.

[image]

I added the lines for later reference.

[image]

So, these results raise a lot more question.

1. How do I interpret "rho" in Equation (1) for example - if I am modeling a type of bird population for with *X(t)*?
2. How do I relate the Killing Function with the Hazard Rate?
3. Is it OK to say that if the *f(t)* is the density distribution of the First-Passage-Times (Refer to Fig-2), then the Hazard rate for the diffusion (2) is:

\begin{gather*}
\lambda (t) = \frac{f(t)}{1-F(t)} & (4)
\end{gather*}

4. If I do not know the killing function - but I observe the first passage time distribution as in Fig-2: Is it possible to solve for the Killing Function?
5. Lastly, in the definition *k(t,x)* is a function of both variables {*x,t*}. In the literature, most of the time is referred as *k(x)*, which is really k(X(t)) since X() is a function of *t*. But if one was to actually apply it - as I did in Fig-1, say:

\begin{gather*}
k(x) = b[(x(t)-a)^{2}]\ & (5)
\end{gather*}

I would have to express it in terms of *X(t)*:

\begin{gather*}
X(t) = a+\sqrt{\frac{t}{b}} & (6)
\end{gather*}

But X(t) is reserved for the diffusion model (2) so it makes it extra confusing.

Note: Assume OP (original poster) is very unintelligent; hence, be very specific, use simple words, do not leave any algebra out, and do not hesitate to curse me out if I wrote something stupid above.

Thank you so much in advance!

```
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[image]

Comment: I personally don't mind if you cross-post (I think some others think differently), but I do think you should include a link to the other post so that people can easily check what progess has been made there without having to search for the question.

Comment: That was a good idea. I added the link thank you.

Comment: But on the other site you neither linked to this question, nor even mentioned that you cross-posted -- why are the people on that site less entitled not to waste their time reproducing results already produced elsewhere than we are?

Comment: I am not very optimistic we'll get any answers anymore; but you are correct again and I will add a link there too. I did not think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about some of the same questions you've posted here. I will try to offer partial answers and perhaps revive this question, and invite someone smarter than me to give full answers to your question.

---

Firstly, lets clear up some notation. In your equation $3)$ you state $Pr(t \leq T \leq t+h \mid T > t)$ but as you condition on $T>t$, the only meaningful statement is $Pr(T \leq t+h \mid T > t)$ because $Pr(t\leq T \vert T>t)$ is simply zero. Usually this would read $Pr(t<T\leq t+\triangle t|T\geq t)$ leaving the possibility of $P(T\leq t)$ open.

Changing your equation $(3)$ to $Pr(T \leq t+h \mid T > t) \approx \lambda (t)h$ there is a minor misnomer. While $\lambda (t)h$ is indeed the *approximate instantaneous probability* of death, it is not the hazard rate. Only $\lambda(t)$ is a meaningful rate. However, both $k(t,x)h$ and $\lambda(t)h$ are meaningful objects. The first is the probability of passing a barrier, given time and position, while the second is probability of passing a barrier, given time.

Now the real difference between equation $(1)$ and $(3)$ stand out: The major difference is the extra piece of information in the killing function; The position $x$. This is a very important piece of information, because given two (or more) positions we can calculate $velocity$, which says something about the speed with which the particle is approaching the barrier. This information is not available in equation $(3)$.

I hope this answers your first 3 questions.

Question 4 would probably be a no. However, given two *different* first passage time distributions, you might be able to say something about the parameters of the models. E.g. a more "right-skewed" FPT density would probably have a lower drift parameter etc. But saying something about position seems futile (however there are HMM approaches that models this).

Question 5 isn't really a question. If it is, then I'm confused about what you're asking.

Comment: Are you still interested in this area?